# Create HTML Table with HandleBars.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I need to create a table with [HandleBars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and json. my proposal is some thing like this :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
 {{NGRID 'json'}}
</script>
```

and register helper for `NGRID` is something like this :

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('NGRID',function(json){

    // create elements <table> and a <tbody>
    var tbl     = document.createElement("table");
    var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

    // cells creation
    for (var j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
        // table row creation
        var row = document.createElement("tr");

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            // create element <td> and text node 
            //Make text node the contents of <td> element
            // put <td> at end of the table row
         var cell = document.createElement("td");    
              var cellText = document.createTextNode("cell is row "+j+", column "+i); 

            cell.appendChild(cellText);
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }

        //row added to end of table body
        tblBody.appendChild(row);
    }

    // append the <tbody> inside the <table>
    tbl.appendChild(tblBody);
    // put <table> in the <body>
    // tbl border attribute to 
    tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");

    return tbl;
});
```

but in my html file the result is something like this :

```
[object HTMLTableElement]
```

but i want to see table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handlebars use the `toString` from the returned object, because this you receive `[object HTMLTableElement]`.

Also, handlebars escape the returned string, to prevent XSS attack. You need to use `Handlebars.SafeString` to your html don't be escaped, in the content that you trust.

For simplicity I return `new Handlebars.SafeString(tbl.outerHTML)` and work.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2RWh/